# Access control point vertices using SQL

Tags: sql, enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, vertices, st-geometry

*ArcGIS Pro 3.2.1; Oracle 18c 10.7.1 EGDB; SDE.ST_GEOMETRY*

Regarding control points:

- Video: [Suppress symbol effect in ArcGIS Pro](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-videos/suppress-symbol-effect-in-arcgis-pro/m-p/1368545)
- [Introduction to control points](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/help/editing/introduction-to-control-points.htm)
- [CIMGeometricEffectAddControlPoints Class](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/3.1/sdk/api-reference/topic1519.html)

Are control point vertex coordinates accessible using SQL? Or are the vertices obscured in the CAD blob?

Comment: Almost certainly a BLOB, similar to representations which includes a new geometry column. You'd need to use the SDK to access this information using VB.net, C# or C++.